# Adding remote VMs in Java VisualVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, visualvm, jstatd

If I open `jvisualvm` and go to `File >> Add Remote Host` I am prompted to create a new remote server entry. I enter a host name of `myapp01.example.org`, and then I see that server show up under the `Remote` section of the `Applications` tree on the left-hand side. When I right-click that server, and click `Add JMX Connection`, I see the following dialog:

[image]

Let's say I have a Java app (WAR deployed to Tomcat) running on `myapp01.example.org:8443`. To SSH into the server, I use username `skroob` and a password of `12345` (hey, that's the combination on my luggage!):

```
ssh skroob@myapp01.example.org
skroob@myapp01.example.org's password: 12345
```

When I fill out the dialog as follows:

- Connection: `myapp01.example.org:8443`
- Username: `skroob`
- Password: `12345`

I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to skroob@myapp01.example.org:8443 using service:jmxLrmi:///jndi/rmi://myapp01.example.org:8443/jmxrmi

I believe this may be because I'm not configuring JMX to be exposed on Tomcat itself. Or maybe I'm just entering the wrong info. Maybe both. Either way:

- What do I need to do to configure this with proper JMX info?
- What do I need to do to configure this properly for `jstatd`?

Comment: You need to create managa-jmx user with username/pwd you want to use to access it. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: Thanks @Nambari (+1) - however please see the [JMX section on that page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet) - there is no mention of a username/password config? Are you sure this isn't something that was deprecated/removed from an earlier version of Tomcat? Thanks again!

Comment: Search for "manager-jmx" section. There you will see how to create users for manager-* role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how JMX connection is specified.  For tomcat the best way is to create a bin/setenv.sh file  This is best because the Apache scripts are already set up to look for it and call it if present.

This is the place where you are intended to set any installation specific parameters.

You will go far with something like this:

```
#
# PORT for debug
export JPDA_ADDRESS='8000'

echo start with 'jpda start' parameters to enable debugging.  Tomcat will listen on $JPDA_ADDRESS

CATALINA_OPTS="\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1299 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=../conf/jmxremote.password \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=../conf/jmxremote.access \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

jmxremote.access:

```
monitorRole readonly
controlRole readwrite
```

jmxremote.password:   This file MUST be READONLY by the ID that starts Tomcat or JMX WILL NOT WORK! i.e. chmod 400 jmxremote.password

```
monitorRole  readpass
controlRole  changepass
```

Basically you are setting up 2 JMX user IDs.  One that can access exposed getters.  The other that can also access setters and arbitary mbean methods.  In practice you'll usually want to supply the latter so you can do more than just look.

**SO....**
In your dialog above it becomes

- Connection: myapp01.example.org:1299
- Username: controlRole
- Password: changepass

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Terry (+1)! A few followup questions. (1) If I define `bin/setenv.sh`, won't Tomcat start up with these options every time? This wouldn't be desirable; only if I needed to start it in debug mode and troubleshoot something. Is there a way to define this in another file and then start Tomcat with that other file instead? (2) Where do I place `jmxremote.access` and `jmxremote.password` files? Thanks again!

Comment: 1. No it does not always start in debug mode.  This just tells it what port debug would run on.  To actually attach with Eclipse for remote debugging instead of "bin/startup.sh" you would start tomcat with the command "bin/startup.sh jpda start"

Comment: technically jmxremote files have to be on the classpath for the JVM (if I remember correctly).  But it is most common to put them in the tomcat/conf directory (same place as context.xml)  NOTE the relative path specification in the setenv.sh